# Jsp display table not shows pagination control

Tags: java, jsp, pagination, displaytag

i used a Jsp display table to perform pagination and its as follows:

```
    <display:table pagesize="${pageSize}" style="width=100%" cellpadding="10"
                             name="publishedExams" id="exam" moduleAware="true"
                            cellspacing="0" requestURI="">
                            <display:column property="grade" style="width=20%" 
                            title="${textResources['ListStudentFinishedExam.MaxGrade']}"/>
    </display:table>
```

the pageSize is a jsp var and its value is 8

the publishedExams is a list of objects that has a property called grade

the publishedExams is populated using the following method:

```
public static List getPage(Query query, int page, int pageSize)
        throws FinderException {

    List results;
    query.setFirstResult(((page - 1) * pageSize));
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    results = query.list();
    return results;
    }

}
```

the query that's passed to this method return 11 entries on dbms but returns 8 only when passed over these method.

the problem is that pagination control doesn't appears it only appears when i return the list contains the actual number that returned from the database(11) and i do that using only `query.list()` i didn't know the actual reason for that

Comment: tried increading pagesize??

Answer (score 0):

This is logical. You defining page size 8, that means 8 entries will be shown per page. So up to 8 entries, there is nothing to paginate. Display table intelligently hides pagination control for that. 
Though if you always want it to show there might be an option.